# Broken Conda Installation After Conda Update Python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have tried upgrading Python version on a Miniconda installation by running `conda update python`. The version was being taken from 3.8 to 3.10. This seems to have broken the installation. No matter what command I run, I get the following:

```
➜  project  conda activate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 16, in <module>
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 15, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 118, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .models.channel import Channel
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/models/channel.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context, Context
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 55, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_round_trip_load
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("No yaml library available. To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml")
ImportError: No yaml library available. To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml
```

Help on fixing this is appreciated.

Comment: The first command results in the same exact error.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Yes.

Comment: Please see if [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392) helps: may be you want to try `conda deactivate` first, then `conda activate`? I am not sure if `project` is a virtual environment created by conda.

Comment: @medium-dimensional I have just done a reinstall and it seems to have helped. I stashed away the envs directory and then copied it back to the new installation. So far, so good!